# Using the redirect function in nuxt extendRoutes

Tags: vue.js, redirect, routes, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am trying to use a function instead of a string to redirect inside of the nuxt extendedRoutes parameter. I seem to be having some issues. I can see it in vue dev tools, but the redirect shows up as undefined. Is there something wrong with my syntax? This is how it works in vue-router so I would assume this is how it works with nuxt.

nuxt.config.js

```js
{
  router: {
    extendRoutes (routes) {

      // This redirect works
      routes.push({
        path: '/team-finder',
        redirect: '/team-finder/teams'
      })


      // This does not work at all
      routes.push({
        path: '/team-finder-redirect',
        redirect: to => '/team-finder/teams'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using the `redirect: to => '/team-finder/teams'`
instead of the `redirect: '/team-finder/teams'`. I think it will be working fine like that

```
routes.push({
    path: '/team-finder-redirect',
    redirect: '/team-finder/teams'
  })
```

Comment: Because sometimes you need to do other things in the function. Also the function was supposed to work according to the docs